# 3 way light switch on a ceiling fan light

Tags: lighting

Trying to switch over to smart rocker switches on a setup. Cannot figure out this 3-way switch. It seems to be complicated by the light being a part of the ceiling fan unit.

Switch A (by itself) controls the LIGHT on the fan.

Switch B (right side of pair) is also on the LIGHT on the fan. 
Those two make up the 3 way.

Switch C (left side of pair) controls the fan by itself.

I feel like I've tried every combination of the black and red wires. The fan switch currently works. The 3-way light switches do not.

It is not the switches themselves as I've installed these in other parts of the house and even rotated this pair out with another working pair to make sure. This is the only place with a ceiling fan light 3 way though. Something in the wiring is not right.

Switch A
[image]

Switch B (right side in photo)
[image]

**WHAT WORKS ON OLD NON-SMART SWITCHES**
I initially tried just switching this over to the smart switches but it did not work. I'm going to try one more time having labeled the three black wires on Switch B and make sure I didn't accidentally switch them. However it seems like which traveler pin I use for the black wire matters on Switch A and B (since the neutral on the smart box comes out of the box and is capped) on the smart switches, so I'll have to try all combinations between the two switches.

SWITCH A (red common, black traveler, neutral traveler)
[image]

SWITCH B (red common, black #1 traveler, neutral traveler, black #2 and #3 capped)[image]

Comment: Can you provide us with views into the back of the boxes?

Comment: The two traveler screws are on the bottom of the box and the common screw is on the side. Sorry I don't have pictures of the backs now, haven't been able to get this  working and now trying to put back on the old switches and can't get those to work either...

Comment: Should have taken a picture of it before I tried anything, but wasn't that smart. There is one more set of 3 way switch in the house, but in that one there is no fan complicating it, and all of the wires are black whereas this setup has red and black.

Comment: Okay, I got the old non-smart switches working. Adding pics in the updated post.

Comment: Is the white wire shown in the non-smart switches not actually a neutral if it's on a traveler screw? Is that why the smart switches aren't working? All the smart setup videos show two black wires on the traveler, one red wire on the common, and then the neutrals capped. However Switch A on the three-way only has one white, one black, and one red, and the white has to be on the traveler screw for the switch to work.

Comment: I can't get the 3-way smart switches to work exactly copying the non-smart configuration. Even tried switching the one traveler wire between the two pins and the best I got was the light switching on and off by itself.

Comment: We still need clear shots of the backs of the boxes...

Comment: Apparently this one setup doesn't have a neutral wire which is why the smart switch isn't working. House was built pre-2011 before the NEC required neutral wires. So it just won't work with these smart switches. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If we knew what was going on fully, we might be able to suggest things that'd work.  Also, what make and model are these smart switches?

Comment: TP-LINK HS210 3-Way switches